# Solution for services being bloated with getter methods?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soa

We are refactoring our core web applications into an 3-tier layer SOA architecture:

- presentation (asp mvc)
- service layer (wcf, net.tcp)
- persistence (sql).

There are about 5 internal web sites, each having their own service layer. 
The services and the UI's share information between each other via DTOs.
The issue is, that most of the service methods are made specifically for the UI and therefore some services get very bulky, e.g:

```
// CompanyService:
CompanyDTO GetByName(String)  
CompanyDTO GetByNameAndCity(String, String)
CompanyDTO GetByNameOrCity(String, String)
CompanyDTO GetByStartsWithNameOrStartsWithCity (String, String)
CompanyDTO GetByNameOrStartsWithCity(String, String)
CompanyDTO GetByNameOrStartsWithCityAndHavingAtLeastOneUser(String, String)
...
CompanyPeopleDTO GetByNameWithPeople(String)
CompanyPeopleDTO GetByNameAndCityWithPeople(String,String)
CompanyPeopleActivityDTO GetByNameWithPeopleAndActivites(String)
...
```

and sometimes there are some very specific queries, like:

```
CompanyAdmin1DTO GetComplexForAdmins1(String, String, String, String, Boolean, Boolean, int) // name,city,country,email, is deleted, is active, founded
CompanyAdmin2DTO GetComplexForAdmins2(String, String, String, Boolean) // name starts with, city starts with, have users
CompanyAdmin3DTO GetComplexForAdmins3(String, String, String, int) // name OR city AND have users
```

We are ending up with a ton of fetch methods, where the actual logic methods are getting lost. 
**Are there better naming conventions for this or even a completely different approach?** (without exposing the domain/persistence)
The web/service layers are physically seperated, so WCF is a must.

Comment: There might be alternatives, but I understand that these are *façade methods* and maybe it seems to be a mess.. but at the end of the day, façades try to adress complexity when using the underlying domain..

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of passing filters to a generic get question, something like that

```
IEnumerable<stuff> GetTheStuff(params Func<stuff, bool> filters)
{
    IQueryable<stuff> resultList = DAL.Stuff.Queryable;
    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        resultList = resultList.Where(filter);
    }
}
```

(syntax is approximate, I don't have an IDE handy)

The advantage is that you can then combine any filter in the call in order to make it do what you need: the query remain explicit and you don't die of `Get*` signatures overload

```
GetStuff(stuff => stuff.Name.Contains("great stuff"), stuff => stuff.CreationDate.Year == 1900 );
```

You can even express your filters as arguments if you need to be explicit in your calls

```
var NamedGreat = stuff => stuff.Name.Contains("great stuff");
var CreatedIn1900 = stuff => stuff.CreationDate.Year == 1900;

GetStuff(NamedGreat, CreatedIn1900);
```

You have plenty of variations on this basis, but it should help you avoid the overly explicit overloads of your methods.

---

This exposes part of the domain, but you could create filters that are able to be expressed against a DTO (for example). Pay attention though not applying the filters to resovled lists of objects (such as DTO themselves) since it would imply you are querying the whole DB instead of filtering in it

Comment: The domain inside the services is isolated and therefore not exposed to the UI. This would work great inside the service layer.

Comment: And you can express your filters as arguments, see edit

Answer (score 0):

A variation to what samy proposed is the following:

You can express GetCompany operation like this:

```
CompanyDTO GetCompany(CompanyQueryBase query)
```

where CompanyQueryBase is an abstract class, with the following data contracts deriving from it:

```
CompanyNameQuery
CompanyNameAndCityQuery
CompanyNameOrCityQuery
CompanyStartsWithNameOrStartsWithCityQuery
CompanyNameOrStartsWithCityQuery
CompanyNameOrStartsWithCityAndAtLeastOneUserQuery
```

You can attach logic to the query classes if you like, but I would prefer to use some sort of query handler factory, which will provide you with a class that can handle and execute such a query. What that means is that basically all your current company related operations will turn into "Handler" classes, and the remaining GetCompany operation will just invoke the factory and execute the query, for example:

```
CompanyDTO GetCompany(CompanyQueryBase query)
{
   // _queryHandlerFactory is a member of the service class
   // it is best to use DI for injecting the specific query handler factory
   // as a dependency to the class
   var queryHandler = _queryHandlerFactory.GetHander(query);
   return queryHandler.Execute();
}
```

This will allow you to keep your current logic mostly untouched, expose just a single Get method (for company) and is easily extensible for future queries you would need to support.

There is however a nasty little problem with that solution. Your clients will not know that CompanyQueryBase is an abstract class (that's because of DataContractSerializer not supporting the xsd abstract complex type declarations, while, oddly enough, XmlSerializer does), meaning that your client will be able to accidentally send you CompanyQueryBase, which will result in an exception on the service side not being able to instantiate an abstract class (because the service knows its abstract).